# Show all network response in android application

Tags: android, android-networking

Is it possible to get all request and response from application in same application without changes device network settings?

Comment: What kind of request and response?

Comment: @DinoTw http, https  post and get request and response

Comment: I don't see why not. Assume the network and server are all working properly, a request sent, a response back.